# Getting a folder ID in as few SQL statements as possible

Tags: php

Consider the database table: folders

```
folders
id   parent_id    name
1    0            a  
2    1            b  
3    2            c
```

'b' is a folder inside 'a' and thus it's parent_id is the id of 'a'.
Folders with a parent_id of 0 simply means it's in the root folder.

I wrote a recursive function in php that helps me get the ID of a path that I'm interested in.

For example:

```
echo get_folder_id('a/b/c'); // 3 (3 SQL queries)  
echo get_folder_id('a'); // 1 (1 SQL query)  
echo get_folder_id('a/b'); // 2 (2 SQL queries)  
echo get_folder_id('a/c'); // false (2 SQL queries)
```

**Problem: For each folder in the path, I had to make a SQL query to the DB server.**

Question: Is there a way I can reduce the number of queries if the path is 'a/b/c'?

Here's my current working solution for reference.

```
function get_folder_id($path, $parent_id=0) {
    $path = explode('/', $path);
    $id = 0;

    //if there's only 1 folder in the path, query the database for the ID
    if (count($path) == 1) {
        $rs = $this->db->select('id')
                ->from('folders')
                ->where('name', $path[0])
                ->where('parent_id', $parent_id)
                ->limit(1)
                ->get();

        if ($rs->num_rows() == 0) return FALSE;

        $result = $rs->row_array();
        return $result['id'];
    }

    foreach($path AS $i=>$p) {
        if ($i==0 && $p=='') continue; //if a path starts with / move on to the next item
        $id = $this->get_folder_id($p, $id);
    }

    return $id;
}
```

Note: I'm using CodeIgniter framework but this isn't related to my question. Just for folks wondering why I used $this->get_folder_id() and $this->db

Comment: what is the max depth for folders ?

Comment: There's no max depth. It's designed in such a way that you can nest folders as much as you want.

Comment: Do you need each ID for each folder in the path?

Comment: Definitely, if I use folder names as the key field, or parent field, then there would be problems where I tried to create a folder with the same name but in 2 different folders.

e.g.
a/notes
b/notes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution I just came up is to use a series of LEFT JOINs on the same table.

```
SELECT tb3.id FROM folders AS tb1
LEFT JOIN folders AS tb2 ON tb2.parent_id=tb1.id
LEFT JOIN folders AS tb3 ON tb3.parent_id=tb2.id
WHERE tb1.name='a' AND tb2.name='b' AND tb3.name='c'
LIMIT 1
```

Based on the number of folders in the path, I can dynamically generate the above SQL.
I'm not sure if this is the perfect solution, but right now it's working as intended.

Any feedback on whether this is a good idea or not is greatly appreciated!

```
$path = 'a/b/c';
$path = explode('/', $path);

$sql = "SELECT tb".count($path).".id FROM folders AS tb1";
for($x=1, $max = count($path); $x<=$max; $x++) {
    $sql .= " LEFT JOIN folders AS tb".($i+2);
    $sql .= " ON tb".($i+2).".parent_id = tb"($i+1).".id";
}

$sql .= " WHERE 1";

foreach($path AS $x => $p) {
    $sql .= " AND tb".($x=1).".name='".$p."'";
}

$sql .= " LIMIT 1";
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple solution for your problem:

Create a recursive stored function in your database and call it from PHP. This should be DB functionality exactly because you have to send many queries from PHP if you implement this in PHP.

Comment: Even if I create the recursive function in DB, it would still run "multiple queries" right? I'm not familiar with stored functions.

Comment: You will run multiple queries, but that's not the issue here. The issue is that you send a request for each query if your PHP function runs all the queries, but if you do this in a stored function, you need only one request to the database server which will run all the queries needing only one request for the result. Using multiple queries is a normal thing, but you need to minimize the number of your requests.

Comment: This way you will send a single command to the database server and you will get an answer, your db server will work out everything internally.

Comment: I see... Woud you be able to show me a simple example of how to create a recursive stored function?

Comment: I would gladly give you an example, but you have never mentioned the relational database management system you are using. Are you using Oracle? Are you using MySQL? Are you using SQL Server? Also, it would be far more elegant to handle your question about stored functions in a separate question, because this question is related to your algorithm, your last comment contained a question about technical implementation of a stored function.

Comment: My apologies, I'm using MySQL

Comment: MySQL doesn't support recursive stored functions, you will have to go with the alternative of using a recursive stored procedure (you can find examples if you search on google for them)